# How to install mongodb on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)

Tags: linux, mongodb, sles

I  download mongodb for distrubution SUSE Linux Enterprise . . I downloaded mongodb from link http://downloads.10gen.com/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-subscription-suse11-2.4.5.tgz and extract it to directory mongodb-linux-x86_64-subscription-suse11-2.4.

When I enter commands :

```
cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-subscription-suse11-2.4 cd bin ./mongod
```

I get error

```
./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpagent.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory .
```

I tried to install packages with command `sudo zypper install libopenssl0_9_8 libsnmp15 slessp1-libsnmp15 snmp-mibs cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-gssapi` , but can't found it . I get error

```
package 'libopenssl0_9_8' not found package 'libsnmp15' not found package 'slessp1-libsnmp15' not found package 'snmp-mibs' not found
```

Can someone help me ?

Can someone tell me step by step howto install mongo db on server :

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 3
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.0-x86_64"
```

I want to install free open source mongdb on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64) , which version of mongodb shoul I download ?

Comment: You did download the enterprise product. Contact 10gen for support.

Comment: It looks like you're using binaries built for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.  Try finding ones appropriate for your operating system, or build `mongodb` from source.

Comment: can someone tell me which version of mongo db should I download  for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64) , and where to find binaris for built for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10

Comment: I don't ant to use commercial mongo db , i want ordinary freee mongo db

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install the Enterprise version which (among other things) has extra, distribution and version specific dependencies (like SNMP libraries, SSL libraries etc.) to support some of the extra features.  Hence you need to satisfy those dependencies to be able to run the Enterprise version and therefore the version must mach your distribution version (that is, you must be running SUSE 11 to use the package you listed, it will not work on SUSE 10).

As mentioned in the comments, to run the Enterprise edition for anything other than a trial period, you need to have a subscription from 10gen, and you would then officially have support for that subscription.  You've indicated that this is not what you want to do and you would rather use the community version.

The community, non-Enterprise version is what you have indicated you want, and that is available here:

http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

It is not a SUSE specific build, it is just a straight binary and is designed to run as-is on any modern Linux version.

If you are looking for a package rather than a binary, details on the supported OS versions for installing from the free version using `yum` are here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

It should be noted that `yast` is not supported specifically, nor is SUSE, but you may be able to install manually using the RPM.